# Website Style Readjust Randomly

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm having a strange issue with a website I recently created. When a user first visits the website, the navigation bar and other items on the header are sitting under the navigation bar, but when the user reloads the page, it appears correctly. I have examined my code, and I'm not sure what's causing the issue. The website can be found [here](http://rileykinsella.lua.bz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have sorted it out, as all stuffs are loading nicely for me.